# Filtering Multiple Drop Down Menu Options Using PHP

Tags: php, sql, filtering

EDIT: I have now attempted to do my PHP code again, it kind of works now but except its prints all the lessons each time you press submit not the lessons around the filter. Also I can't seem to connect two tables together when filtering. The Instructor's name is from a different table instructor and I would like to pick this up.  Here is my PHP code.

```
<?php
include('connect-db.php');

if($_POST){
  if($_POST['Days'] == 'Monday') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Monday'";
  }elseif($_POST['Days'] == 'Tuesday') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Tuesday'";
  }elseif($_POST['Days'] == 'Wednesday') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Wednesday'";
  }elseif($_POST['Days'] == 'Thursday') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Thursday'";
  }elseif($_POST['Days'] == 'Friday') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Friday'";
  }elseif($_POST['Days'] == 'Saturday') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Saturday'";
  }elseif($_POST['Days'] == 'Sunday') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Sunday'";
  }elseif($_POST['Days'] == 'All') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson";
  }

  if($_POST['Instructors'] == 'Trevor') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson INNER JOIN instructor 
      ON lesson.Instructor_ID = instructor.Instructor_ID WHERE Forename='Trevor'";
  }elseif($_POST['Instructors'] == 'Laura') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson INNER JOIN instructor 
      ON lesson.Instructor_ID = instructor.Instructor_ID WHERE Forename='Laura'";
  }elseif($_POST['Instructors'] == 'Rachel') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson INNER JOIN instructor 
      ON lesson.Instructor_ID = instructor.Instructor_ID WHERE Forename='Rachel'";
  }elseif($_POST['Instructors'] == 'Ryan') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson INNER JOIN instructor 
      ON lesson.Instructor_ID = instructor.Instructor_ID WHERE Forename='Ryan'";
  }elseif($_POST['Instructors'] == 'Steve') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson INNER JOIN instructor 
      ON lesson.Instructor_ID = instructor.Instructor_ID WHERE Forename='Steve'";
  }elseif($_POST['Instructors'] == 'All') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson INNER JOIN instructor 
      ON lesson.Instructor_ID = instructor.Instructor_ID";
  }

  if($_POST['TypeLessons'] == 'Keeping Fit') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Type_of_Lesson='Keeping Fit'";
  }elseif($_POST['TypeLessons'] == 'How to Swim') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='How to Swim'";
  }elseif($_POST['TypeLessons'] == 'Relaxing Sessions') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Relaxing Sessions'";
  }elseif($_POST['TypeLessons'] == 'Being Sporty') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Being Sporty'";
  }elseif($_POST['TypeLessons'] == 'All') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson";
  }

  $result = mysql_query($query);

  if(!$result) {
  echo 'Could not get data: ' . mysql_error();
  }

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "Lesson ID: {$row["Lesson_ID"]} <br> " .
       "Name: {$row["Name"]} <br> " .
       "Day: {$row["Day"]} <br> " .
       "Start Date: {$row["Start_Date"]} <br> " .
       "Start Time: {$row["Start_Time"]} <br> " .
       "End Time: {$row["End_Time"]} <br> " .
       "Instructor: {$row["Forename"]} <br> " .
       "Type of Lesson: {$row["Type_of_Lesson"]} <br> " .
       "Number of Places: {$row["No_of_Places"]} <br> <br> ";
}

}
?>
```

I have been trying to filter multiple drop down menu options so that when the user clicks 'search lessons' the queries appear. But for some reason I keep getting the same error message: Notice: Undefined index: Days. 
Even though the php code should be picking it up, it doesn't seem to be and I can't figure it out. This is my code below, note I haven't finished selecting all my PHP. 
Also how do I print out these queries too once I select these options upon selecting PHP. Thank you so much.

```
<form action="tester_filter.php" method="post">
<select name="Days">
<option value="All" selected="selected">All days</option>
<option value="Monday">Monday</option>
<option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
<option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
<option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
<option value="Friday">Friday</option>
<option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
<option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
</select>
<select name="Instructors">
<option value="All" selected="selected">All instructors</option>
<option value="Trevor">Trevor</option>
<option value="Laura">Laura</option>
<option value="Rachel">Rachel</option>
<option value="Ryan">Ryan</option>
<option value="Steve">Steve</option>
</select>
<select name="TypeLessons">
<option value="All" selected="selected">All types</option>
<option value="Keeping Fit">Keeping Fit</option>
<option value="How to Swim">How to Swim</option>
<option value="Relaxing Sessions">Relaxing Sessions</option>
<option value="Being Sporty">Being Sporty</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search lessons" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Show us all the code for tester_filter.php, so we can make a correct answer, unless the php tags are everything thats in it??

Comment: That was all in it for now, because I was trying to get the 'Days' to be picked up, I am unsure how to print out these queries after. I looked online and some use AJAX which I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if($_POST){
  if($_POST['Days'] == 'Monday') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Monday'";
  }elseif($_POST['Days'] == 'Tuesday') {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Tuesday'";
  }
}
?>
```

try this one

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have gotten rid of the Undefined index error message. But how I do print out the details from the database once creating these queries? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to fix the notice error use the below code.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  if($_POST['Days'] == 'Monday') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Monday'";
  }
  elseif($_POST['Days'] == 'Tuesday') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Tuesday'";
  }
}
```

alternatively you can also check by below code

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
     // process, validate or save to DB  $_POST values,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your PHP script is located in **tester_filter.php**  like the form suggests (you didn't actually state its there), I'm not sure what you're expecting to get out, the Days is being picked up, however you're only setting a variable called Query to a string, and not doing anything with it.

In each of the if statements, do a debugging

```
if($_POST['Days'] == 'Monday') {
//A check we're having the variable pass through 
echo "this should say monday";
$query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE Day='Monday'";
}
```

If you're trying to check if you're selection is good (it looks okay), then select monday and see if the echo is output, then you're looking good.

You can't just assign a Query without a connection to a database, you need a connection string, such as, for example:

```
//Connection variables
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";
//Connect to MySQL
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else{ 
    echo "Connected successfully";
}
```

Then once you have that very base, you can start Querying the database, using what you've done with $Query.

It's probably too much for me to explain so i'll leave as many helpful links as I think you'll need to help you on your way.

[Connect to a MySQL Database from PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

[Pulling data from a MySQL Database, Querying the Database through PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

[List of MySQLi functions and what they do](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

[Another list of MySQLi functions and what they do](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp)

[Another guide on how to select information from a MySQL Database](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm)

Good luck, and comment if you have any problems.

Comment: Thank you, got this to work in the end! Those links have been helpful!

Comment: Glad I could help!